# Can I tell Rstudio an .rscript file is still an R script file

Tags: r, rstudio

I like to name `Rscript` scripts with '*.rscript'.
When I do this Rstudio prompts that it won't be a R script anymore.
Can I tell Rstudio to leave it as I know what I am doing (I created it with the menu "create R script Ctrl+Shift+N" after all...)

[image]

Comment: I guess Rstudio will read only predefined extensions. It's like asking Excel to open `.myexcel` files. Probably won't happen unless I'm not familiar with something?

Comment: Aye. They are a "compiled-in" settings (actually embedded into minified, cached javascript) for the ACE editor RStudio uses as a source editor. There's not even a hidden "config" file, but you can post a msg to their support forum with this as a feature request. On OS X (you seem ot be on linux) I can associate a `.rscript` file with RStudio.app in the OS and RStudio will open it and I am able to toggle the menu at the bottom of the source pane to have it think it's an R program file (i.e. get syntax editing/etc). I suspect a similar feature exists for you.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: thank you for you insight, I will fill a feature request, feel free to write this as answer.

Comment: @Roman Lustrik: indeed archaic software might still ask for predefined extensions... hopefully we can still do the right thing.

Comment: Rstudio is an opensource project. Feel free to make a [pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio).